# write a rule to detect customer location in a department in a store based on visits

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rule-engine, complex-event-processing

I am new to Drools and have some questions. I am working on creating rules which detects customers in departments in a store.

My model is as below:

Customer: Id, Point(x,y)

Department: Id, Rectangle

CustomerEvent

I currently have customers represented with x,y location or a point and a department is represented by rectangle.

1.) How do I write a rule to detect if a customer is in a rectangle?

2.) If a customer changes location within a department at least 2 times, trigger an event.  How do I write a rule to detect if the customer is in a department and has changed location two times?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

### Customer

public class CustomerObj {

```
public CustomerObj(String custId, Integer timestamp) {
    super();
    this.custId = custId;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
private String custId;
private long timestamp;
private Integer classification;
private Point location;
private Department department;


public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(Integer timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
public String getCustId() {
    return custId;
}
public void setCustId(String custId) {
    this.custId = custId;
}
public Integer getClassification() {
    return classification;
}
public void setClassification(Integer classification) {
    this.classification = classification;
}
public Point getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(Point location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}
```

}

### Department

public class Department {

```
public Department(Integer departmentId) {
    super();
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

private Integer departmentId;
private Rectangle deptLocation;

public Integer getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public boolean containsCustomer(CustomerObj c) {
    if (this.deptLocation.contains(c.getLocation())) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Surely you know how to detect when a point is within the boundaries of a rectangle? Also, counting changes of location with a customer isn't too difficult. What Java code do you have for Customer, Department, CustomerEvent, and what rules have you tried so far?

Comment: yes. easy to detect a point within a rectangle and change in location for a customer. I don't know how to exactly depict that in a drl. I am also using CEP as the data will be available in a stream. I am working on that. I am adding the code for my two objects, Customer and Department. An example drl will he helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Rectangle and Point are from java.awt, things are rather simple.

```
rule "customer in department"
when
    CustomerObj( $cid: custId, $p: point )
    Department( $did: departmentId, $dloc: deptLocation,
                $dloc.contains( $p ) )
then
    System.out.println( "customer " + $cid + " in " + $did );
end
```

As for the movements, you'll need an CustomerEvent showing customer and department id and the location.

```
rule "customer moves frequently in same department"
when
    CustomerEvent( $cid: custId, $did: dptmtId, $p: Point )
    $dep: Department( departmentId == $did )
    $cust: CustomerObj( custId == $cid, department == $dep, moves >= 1 )
then
    // whatever
end
```

Note that you'll need additional rules for changing the department reference in a customer and for registering the 1st move, and, possibly for counting the moves beyond the second move.

Comment: Laune, Thanks for the examples. I am trying to track the customer objects in a drl. If the customer has the same cid, it is supposed to be the same customer. How can I track customers coming in the form of streaming data where the same customer (having the same cid) enters the department again. Can I write that logic in a drl?

Comment: Yes, one can. - Since you didn't say or show that my answer is useful I'm not going to extend this into another Q&A.

Comment: So, if the "rule customer in department" is OK, you can easily modify it for registering the number of observations within the same department, or if the customer moves into another one. However, your information does not include event like customer leaving the store and what should happen with that customer, is the same human being recognized as being the same Customer when she returns, etc. etc. Please understand that such details are essential for rule programming (which doesn't make it different from programming in general). Perhaps another Q with sufficient details? Also, try yourself!

Comment: Good Point. In this case, the scope of the application/use-cases are very constrained. This is a sample application.. I don't have use-cases like "customer leaving the store". The use cases I am interested in as :  a) Customers in a department and track them "move" = 5 times. b) Time spent by customers in a Department. I am trying it out myself.

Comment: If you don't have an event "customer leaves" they'll all spend from here to eternity in some department?

Comment: yes, they will move between departments or will be part of a big store. The Streaming data which represents customer movements will be simulated by a script.

Comment: Ah so - as long as it is just a simulation you can kill the program to set them free ;-)